# TWRP 3.3.1 help

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, shell

I'm using TWRP 3.3.1 right now with device with dead screen. So I need to use adb commands to do backup and wipe. I did read the commandline guide available at https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html. I believe client side/script is supposed to be used in recovery adb shell right?

Given that it is correct. I am trying to backup and wipe my partitions. Problem is wipe command, format command, and backup command does not work. I checked that mount command works.

Help me with the solution and if the available commands differ in 3.3.1 please let me know what are all available commands.

note: it seems like shell script use script in /sbin/sh if this is incorrect shell script to be used tell me which shell script i am suppose to use and how to chroot to it (is that even correct term?)

Comment: what exact command did you type, and what is the error message? *'adb pull /tmp/recovery.log'* will tell you

Comment: @alecxs i tried `backup` and `wipe`  both command were "not found" it means either it is not available in 3.3.1 or different in 3.3.1 So I need to know the way around.

Comment: that is not exact command, you are missing prefix twrp and arguments

Comment: @alecxs well that worked like a charm. The guide at TWRP was not clear enough for me. Thanks.